# Choosing right Tokenizer in Elastic 5.4 for emulate contains like queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, n-gram

I am using Elastic 5.4 to implement suggestion/ completion like functionality and facing issue in choosing the right tokenizer for my requirements. Below is example:

There are **4 documents** in the index as follows with the content as mentioned below:

DOC 1: Applause

DOC 2: Apple

DOC 3: It is an Apple

DOC 4: Applications

DOC 5: There is_an_appl

**Queries**

Query 1: Query String '*App*' should return all 5 documents.

Query 2: Query String '*Apple*' should return only document 2 and document 3.

Query 3: Query String '*Applications*' should return only document 4.

Query 4: Query String '*appl*' should return all 5 documents.

**Tokenizer**

I am using the following tokenizer in Elastic and I am seeing all documents returned for Query 2 and Query 3.

The analyzer is applied to fields of type '**text**'.

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I restrict the results to return documents which contain an exact match of the query string either as part of existing word or a phrase or a exact word( *I have mentioned the expected results are provided in the queries above*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using an [`nGram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer instead of [`edgeNGram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) one. The latter only indexes prefixes, while the former will index prefixes, suffixes and also sub-parts of your data.

Change your analyzer definition to this instead and it should work as expected:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",          <---- change this
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Val. I think the max_gram has to be updated as well for my tokenizer otherwise query string of length > 3 will not return results if standard analyzer is used at search time for user entered query string.

Comment: How did you define the mapping of your fields?

Comment: I have mentioned "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer" to the field in the mapping to override the default mapping for the field

Comment: Then that analyzer will be used at indexing + searching time. And if you have a `query_string` query, you can also specify that same analyzer at query time if you want.

Comment: Agreed. However, At search time, I am looking to search for the terms the user has typed in and have provided "standard" as analyzer at query time.

Comment: Good, then in that case you need to increase `max_gram` indeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149670/discussion-between-findingtheone-and-val).